Coonvertig yt-dlp EXE arguments to internal script ydl_opts
I create a simple json file with multiple videos for audio extract to use it in my script:
def run_yt_dlp_data(cfg):
    
    music_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Música/tmp')
    
    for t in cfg.values():
    
        artist = t[0]
        title = t[1]
        url = t[2]
        
        jman = True if len(t) <= 3 else t[3]
        
        fmt = 'vorbis' if jman else 'mp3'
        bit = '256k' if jman else '128k'
        
        cmd_line = ['yt-dlp']
        cmd_line.append('-x')
        cmd_line.append('--audio-format')
        cmd_line.append(fmt)
        cmd_line.append('--audio-quality')
        cmd_line.append(bit)
        if jman: cmd_line.append('--embed-thumbnail')
        cmd_line.append('--ppa')
        cmd_line.append('ffmpeg: -metadata artist=\"{}\" -metadata title=\"{}\"'.format(artist, title))
        cmd_line.append('-P')
        cmd_line.append(music_dir)
        cmd_line.append('-o')
        cmd_line.append('{} - {}.%(ext)s'.format(artist, title))
        cmd_line.append(url)
        
        subprocess.run(cmd_line)

Now, I'm adding yt-dlp as a mdoule to my script but for me the documentation is mostly unclear about how to use it on internal python scripts based on EXE giving arguments, so this what I have so far:
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
def run_yt_dlp_pip(cfg):
    
    music_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Música/tmp')
    
    for t in cfg.values():
        
        artist = t[0]
        title = t[1]
        url = t[2]
        
        jman = True if len(t) <= 3 else t[3]
        fmt = 'vorbis' if jman else 'mp3'
        bit = '256k' if jman else '128k'
        
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': fmt,
            'outtmpl': '{} - {}.%(ext)s'.format(artist, title)
        }
        
        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([url])

Any help about how to convert the commandline arguments used in run_yt_dlp_data to ydl_opts?

You can look through https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/master/yt_dlp/options.py to find the destination of each option.
